# iOS - Adding Obj-C Files in Watch Extension causing Error

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode7, watchkit

I have a project (objective-c) in which i have added WatchKit App in Swift. Now i want to use Objective-C classes in swift. I am using Xcode 7.3

I created Bridging Header, added into Swift Compiler inside Build setting of app target and watch extension.

The problem i am facing is that to access objective-c class i must add the class to target membership of Watch Extension. As soon as i do complier gives error inside Watch Extension but of the classes i never ever added to watch extension. Like my main viewcontroller giving error that it cant find UIViewController class from which it is being inherited.

The error is right because it is compiling it for Watch Extension which i never added into watch app or extension.

What could be the problem? How can i solve this issue that is occurring out of no where as i have added watch app in my other apps using same methodology.

**Edit:**
Here are the error i am getting on classes that are not added into extension.

[image]

Comment: You realize that your error is correct, and that you cannot add a UIViewController class to a watch extension, so what is in these objective-c classes?  A UIViewController?  I think so.

Comment: No i never added those files. I only am trying to add single .m that is inherited from NSObject. Those UIViewControllers were never ever added still building project gives error in WatchKit Extension

Comment: Look through the error results generated by the compiler. On what file does it indicate there are viewControllers in the wrong place? What are the exact error messages?

Comment: @OwenHartnett please check my edit i have added error images. Those UIView and UIViewControllers are not added into extension but it is giving error.

Comment: Adding a swift file from main project into extension have no problems at all but as soon as i add .m it generated errors

Comment: It appears from the error messages that both LightBoxViewCon and ContainerView are subclasses of UIViewController.  You also define UIViews in there.  They should be subclasses of WKInterfaceController, and you don't use views in the normal iOS sense, you need a storyboard in your watchkitapp, and you need to get IBOutlets to those objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue that was causing the files to appear in other targets (WatchKit). I had created My custom PCH File and added it manually into my main project.

Later on when i created new target (WatchKit) it automatically copied PCH files settings. Now the classes added into PCH files were being complied for WatchKit too, hence the errors.

Took my time and it came out as a simple mistake.

Comment: Can you explain how you solved it? I tried removing the PCH file also adding ifdef TARGET_OS_IOS but both didn't workout. I am still facing the same issue.

Comment: @Hassy I am also adding a Swift watch app to an Objective-C iOS project. I know you just select File -> New -> Target -> Watch App. But do we have to add the bridging-header file manually or will Xcode do it automatically? Also I think I read that the iOS target and watch app target cannot be the same name. Is this correct? e.g. MyAmazingApp + MyAmazingWatchApp?

Comment: Xcode automatically creates the PCH file for you, for some reason you do it manually, one must check if it is added correctly for app + extensions. 

Every extension is a separate target. The app display name can be same but its bundle identifier + distribution profiles are seperate.